# Spring Boot Actuator - Get your own /info data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is there a way to get your own `/info` response from the service?

I am having one service that is exposed to frontend and I would like to aggregate `/info` responses from all of the internal services, and also add my own.

However, the only option to get my own data is to call myself ... And I would like to avoid that unnecessary HTTP call to my own service.

Can I somehow dig that information from some kind of actuator bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `info` endpoint enabled you can simply autowire (or obtain from the context) [`InfoEndpoint`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator/latest/org/springframework/boot/actuate/info/InfoEndpoint.html) which will be created by [`InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/info/InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration.html) and call it's `info` method :

```
@Service
class Svc {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Svc.class);
    private InfoEndpoint infoEndpoint;

    Svc(final InfoEndpoint infoEndpoint) {
        this.infoEndpoint = infoEndpoint;
    }
    
    void perform() {
        LOG.info("{}", infoEndpoint.info());
    }

}
```